# Shorten text in query

Tags: php, mysql

I am hoping one of the gurus can help (please!)

I would like the text in this query (link_text) to be shortened to 28 characters?

```
$sources_html .= '<a href="'.$row_sources["url"].'">'.$row_sources["link_text"].'</a>';
```

---

COMPLETE QUERY

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sources WHERE CatID='$id' order by source_id";

$result4=mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));
$sources_html='';
while($row_sources = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)){
$sources_html .= '<a 
href="'.$row_sources["url"].'">'.$row_sources["link_text"].'</a>';
}

<?  if($sources_html){echo "$sources_html";}?>
```

---

Comment: substr($row_sources["link_text"],0,28)

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: where do I add this code into the query?

Comment: so what did you do ?

Comment: tadman is all "doom and gloom" with lot's of rhetoric and negative warnings with no real answers.  The code does not have $_post or $_get in it so why go there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of functions **substr** or **mb_substr**

For texts that each char has exactly one byte you can use

```
$linkText28 = substr($row_sources["link_text"], 0, 28);
```

for multibyte string use rather

```
$linkText28 = mb_substr($row_sources["link_text"], 0, 28);
```

For details see:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

Answer (score 0):

Before appendding the link to `$sources_html`, I would look up and edit the value, like so:

```
if(strlen($row_sources["link_text"]>28)){
    $row_sources["link_text"] = substr($row_sources["link_text"], 0, 25).'...';
}
```

I am using **25** as I replace the last 3 characters with dots (...), to better understand the string was chopped, up to you ... :P

if you use UTF-8 chars you might need `mb_substring`.

Comment: First thing inside your while ;)
It is performed at the PHP level

Comment: Hmm, Martijn Pieters deleted my thank you which included the answer.  I totally get the "thank you" concept but in this case, hexYeah was close but not exactly, so I included the answer with the thank you.  What is the protocol then in this case?

Comment: Your answer is based on mine... I sincerely hope you will consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: Choosing yours will not give you rep anyway... Its normal you might have to tweak it a little and its not like you came up with it anyway... ... ...

Comment: haha, I wasn't interested in REP, I was trying to say the answer was based on yours.  TBH it's not very obvious how to mark it as the answer.

Comment: It's a muted/grayed check mark beside the answer... sorry its just getting frustrating helping ppl and not getting rep :P

Answer (score 0):

$sources_html .= ''.$row_sources["link_text"] = substr($row_sources["link_text"], 0, 25).'...'.'';